# Custom Icons with Vertical Nav Component

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning

I'm using the Lightning [vertical navigation](https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/components/vertical-navigation/#site-main-content) component, and I want to use a custom icon for each menu item. In the [Component Reference documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:verticalNavigation/example#lightningcomponentdemo:exampleVerticalNavIcon) there's an example for referencing icons that are built into Salesforce:

```
<lightning:verticalNavigationSection label="Reports">
  <lightning:verticalNavigationItemIcon
       label="Recent"
       name="reports_recent"
       iconName="utility:clock" />
```

I'd like to use custom icons that my organization has developed. Is there a way to reference non-Salesforce icons in the vertical navigation component the same way?